# charging Previous variable

Tags: php, javascript, html

code

```
<div id="dialog"><?php echo $txt; ?></div>
<body>
<div id="warper">
</div>
<footer>
<?php if ($_GET[y]==yes)
{
$txt='thankyou';
load dialog javascript;
}
</footer>
</body>
```

but because `$txt` is top of `$txt='thankyou';` when dialog load nothing show . anyway without change code Balance set in $txt???

Comment: "If I've decided to eat dinner when I come home, why am I hungry now?!?"

Answer (score 2):

You will have to reorder your code.  You also probably don't want an empty div if the condition fails.  Try:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET[y]=="yes") {
        echo '<div id="dialog">thank you</div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: my code in header.php and download.php is separate . i cant write download code in header.php

Comment: You can never "go back" and change the value.  Either move the condition into your header or move the div out of the header.  Otherwise, you'll probably need to use JavaScript to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: How is `echo` a download code? `$_GET` is available wherever you are. Just have two `if ($_GET["y"] == "yes")` blocks in different locations. Also, writing bare strings (without quotes) is a bad practice, and will come back to haunt you some day.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ($_GET[y]==yes)
{
$txt='thankyou';
load dialog javascript;
}
?>
<div id="dialog"><?php echo $txt; ?></div>
<body>
<div id="warper">
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: No way. How might code work in different way if it's the same code?